# Wireless earbuds 18650 battery high pitch noise

Tags: battery-charging

I've decided to replace 18650 in my T9 TWS earbuds charging case. Went with Sony. Case initiates with all segments on the LCD lit up. All good so far. Once I put the earbuds in, I can hear "modem like" low volume high pitch noise. LCD shows some bogus battery charge level (very low). LCD shows charging for few seconds and turns off.

Battery is for sure charged and healthy. The same now happens with the original battery (which I've charged outside of the case).

Can it be voltage to high for cheap built-in charging circuit?

---

Here is the detail:

[image]

[image]

Gray cable in the middle leads to the LCD. On the left there is MicroUSB in, on the right USB out (case can act as a battery pack).

Comment: No, the battery should have nothing to do with it. Did you change something else?

Comment: @winny No, I didn't. Also I didn't touch the circuit. It actually behaves quite weirdly. If I now add fully charged battery, it starts charging the case from 0 (on the display) after connecting the cell to the case. Even with battery, which was before disconnecting "charged" to 75pct by the built-in charger. It actually begins from 0 and successfully charges even with no battery connected when connected to USB. I guess some sort of wireless power transfer... :) Earbuds start charging only when the case is on USB, if not connected, it just hums. I'm actually suspecting it is some logic error in

Comment: `I've decided to replace 18650 ..` ... does that mean that you actually replaced the cell? ... what did you do to replace it?

Comment: @jsotola it is soldered.

Comment: so the answer to @winny question should be `yes, i reworked the solder connections`

Comment: @jsotola yes, on the battery, otherwise the wires are untouched.